# Contour returns doubled number of objects when edge is thick

Tags: opencv, image-recognition

I am using opencv findContours to find number of objects in the image. However it always returns a duplicated number because it will detect both the inner and outer edge.

However i cannot use RETR_EXTERNAL because there is still object within the object.

```
    import cv2 
    import numpy as np 
    img = cv2.imread('image.jpg') 
    canvas = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)
    img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img2gray,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    im2,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_L1)
    print(len(contours))
```

For example this image: https://pasteboard.co/Iz3wMjg.png

It returns 6 in this case, however there are only 3 circles. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: On such a simple image, thinning will work perfectly. But maybe this is a toy image ?

Comment: Ya, the real picture is similar but more complex. I tried thinning, it will produce a cross in between

Comment: Not a good idea to provide nor representative images.